# Google Sheets: adjust rows in column B to sit in front of the same rows of column A (script)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have column A and column B in my sheet with the following set of records:

```
COLUMN A   COLUMN B
value1     value1
value2     value4
value3     value6
value4
value5
value6
...
```

So some records are missing in column B.
Using script, I need to update column B, so it should look like:

```
COLUMN A   COLUMN B
value1     value1
value2     
value3     
value4     value4
value5
value6     value6
...        ...
```

Comment: Do you have a header row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the code below

```
function myFunction() {
  let colB = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("B:B");
  let colBValues = colB.getValues().filter(val => val[0].length > 0);
  let colAValues = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("A:A").getValues();
  colB.clear();
  colBValues.forEach(valB => {
    let r = colAValues.findIndex(valA => valA[0] == valB[0]);
    if(r !== -1) {
      r = r + 1; //because js array index begins at 0 but gSheet begins at 1
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(r, 2).setValue(valB[0]);
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use script only if something is not possible using a formula. In this case you could get the desired outcome in column C by entering the following formula in C1.
`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(if(len(A:A),VLOOKUP(A:A,B:B,1,false),),))`

Comment: The thing is that my data in columns A and B is already pre-populated using a quite heavy script, so I do need to adjust existing column B rather than adding another one...